# Unable to click on Dynamics365 drop down menu using Selenium/c# - "ElementNotVisibleException"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm

I'm automating Dynamics365 CRM using Selenium/C#. Able to click and drop the menu, but unable to find and click on the "Submitted" option (line 2 code). Getting this exception: *OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: '//*[contains(text(),'Submitted')]'*. Appreciate any ideas how to handle this issue. Also I've given the gui and html below. Highlighted in last picture is the field where drop down is.

[image: function used]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If anyone knows how to change the focus to the dropdown also is helpful. Thanks

Comment: Per a developer its using Option Sets. Need some pointers on this and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Automating/scraping Dynamics 365 on the WEB UI side can be difficult, I have been there. The UI form uses a lot of JS event handling, css class naming to show/hide values, boxes etc..
By relying on just calling "click" event on elements, i'm sure will be difficult if not impossible for you to reach your goals. For instance, the elements are sometimes sensitive to mouse hover **and** click events, at the same time! Are you able to interface with local js objects?? Because there is a way easier way. Dynamics 365 uses a local js Form API called Xrm so google that. Here is an example of getting list of attributes available on the form: Run this in browser console.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute()
```

It will return a list of attribute names. Find the attribute name that corresponds to you dropdown field. To get a list of available option values (key/value pair) you can simple do:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("industrycode").getOptions()
// industrycode in this example is a standard attribute of account entity
// returns [{ name: <string>, value: <int>  }, {...} ]
```

Find the correct value and set the field like so:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("industrycode").setValue([value])
```

Then save the form.